# Oracle SQL Bulk Update of feild

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do a bulk update of a License field  for around 1000 users in a table

```
 update License set license=E1 where UID =('100') 

 update License set license=KB where UID=('107')

 update License set license=E5 where UID=('110')
```

And so on..
Is there a better way to do it? How to frame the query to do the updates at one go..?

Comment: How do you get the UID and license values?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: License is randomly provided to UID.I have those values in a xls. I am using Oracle.

Comment: xls? Excel file?

Comment: Better use formula in Excel to prepare update statements. Let us say UID is in cel A1 for first value and License is in cell B1. Then you can  use something like =CONCATENATE("update License set license=", B1," where UID =('",A1,"');"). Then just copy and paste results. Not bulk but fast approach.

Answer (score 0):

From a database performance perspective, the fastest update statement would use a case expression:

```
update license
set license =
    case
        when id = 100 then 'E1'
        when id = 107 then 'KB'
        when id = 110 then 'E5'
    end
where id in (100, 107, 110);
```

Batching similar commands is one of the most important performance improvements you can make and will avoid overheads like network lag and query parsing. On the other hand, the more complicated SQL statement may not be as easy to recreate from a spreadsheet. If there are only 1000 rows, and this process will only be run a small number of times, and the network latency is low, the SQL may not be worth optimizing.